# Bootstrap stretch badge

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm having a hard time to get the a bootstrap badge stretched over the full width. See the enclosed example.

Some assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

 <body>
  <div class="card-body ml-2 m-2  p-0 ">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr-1">B</button>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">

           <div class="container-fluid m-0 p-0">

            <div class="row ">
              <div class="col-sm-4 btn-group" role="group">
               <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary text-dark m-1 p-1" type="button">XXX</button>
               <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary text-dark m-1 p-1" type="button">YYY</button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4 btn-group" role="group">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm ml-1"><span class="badge badge-success text-uppercase center p-1 m-0" style="width: 100%">812</span>
               </button>
              </div>
            </div>

         </div>

         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-1">S</button>

      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: which button did you want to stretch over to full width? The one with 812 text? You only put `col-sm-4` for the column that contains the button. That's why it only stretch 1/3 of the row.

Comment: ... that easy ... thanks!